# Drupal 8 - LDAP / Active Directory working?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, drupal-8

I'm new to Drupal and recently installed 8.1.2 and the LDAP module. I've been trying for 2 days to connect to our local Active Directory. However, every time I tried to run the server test I got an error: "**Failed to bind to server. ldap error #49 Invalid credentials**".

I'm sure the settings are correct and the credentials definitely are (I tested direct in Active Directory and in PHP). I also tried an online LDAP connection and that failed with the same error too. I thought maybe it's just the test that doesn't work so I tried logging in with a known AD account but it didn't work. As a final test I just installed Drupal 7 (and the modules for that) instead and with the same settings everything worked perfectly first time (tests ran as expected and I logged in with an AD account).

I know the LDAP module for 8 is in development mode but it seems to imply it is working. Has anyone got this working though? Please can you let me know whether I could be overlooking something simple with the settings in 8 or if it is a bug. I really don't want to use Drupal 7, but we definitely need our users to be able to log in using their network details.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer in the issue queue?

Comment: did you have any luck? 9 months later this module is difficult to configure.